# Voting (especially upvoting) Matters!

Tags: discussion, voting

Just a reminder to those visiting the site to upvote good content when you see it. The site will only continue to grow if we encourage good questions/answers and get the users posting them more involved in the site. More upvotes means more users with high rep, which means more users who can edit posts and tags, use the review queues, and offer bounties for other questions/answers. SE also tracks the reputation of users for the purpose of deciding whether a site can graduate or if it stays open.

Reviving this post as a reminder: Voting Matters, both for gaining new users, retaining current users, and showing the SE network that this community is important enough to put resources towards.

TLDR:
[image: Go vote banner]

Comment: +100. I could not agree more. Here's a list of the top voters on our site: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all. Things drop rapidly after the people who have voted 100+ times.

Comment: Hello Tyberius, I'm wondering if I can copy this post onto Operations Research Meta (with credits) as our site would definitely benefit from more voting from the community?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire sure, that's no problem.

Comment: Thanks! ${}{}{}$